# filtering 3D array using data in similar array

Tags: arrays, r, optimization

I have two 3-D arrays, one of which contains data and the other contains metadata. The metadata is a date signature, so an example can be produced with the following:

```
datamatrix <- array(data = c(rep(0,9), rep(0,9),(sample(0:100, 9)/1000), (sample(30:50, 9)/100), (sample(70:80,9)/100), (sample(30:50,9)/100), rep(0,9), rep(0,9)), dim = c(3,3,8))
timematrix <- array(data = c(sample(1:20), sample(30:50, 9), sample(70:90, 9), sample(110:130,9), sample(150:170,9), sample(190:210,9), sample(230:250,9), sample(260:280,9)), dim = c(3,3,8))
```

I wish to construct a new 3D array filled with the data from the first matrix (`datamatrix`) and a bunch of `NA`'s such that the element `i` in the `datamatrix` falls into its corresponding date (derived from the corresponding metadata in `timematrix`) in a final `workingdata` 3D array like so:

```
workingdata <- array(data = NA,
                 dim = c(3,3,365))

for (i in 1:length(datamatrix)){
  location <- i
  locationguide <- location%%9
  locationfinal <- locationguide%%3
  if (locationfinal == 0){
    a <- 3
    b <- 3
  }
  if (locationfinal == 1){
    a <- 1
    b <- 1
  }  
  if (locationfinal == 2){
    a <- 1
    b <- 2
  }
  if (locationfinal == 3){
    a <- 1
    b <- 3
  }
  if (locationfinal == 4){
    a <- 2
    b <- 1
  }
  if (locationfinal == 5){
    a <- 2
    b <- 2
  }
  if (locationfinal == 6){
        a <- 2
        b <- 3
      }
  if (locationfinal == 7){
    a <- 3
    b <- 1
  }
  if (locationfinal == 8){
    a <- 3
    b <- 2
  }
  value <- datamatrix[i]
  day <- timematrix[i]
  workingdata[a,b,day] <- datamatrix[i]
}
```

The dataset I'm working with is thousands of columns wide and equivalently long-rowed.  The current method does the job, however it would take forever using a `for` loop in the actual data, and coding it would be ridiculous because of all of the `if`'s this requires.  Does anyone know of a better method for filtering data such as this?

For a viewer-friendly concept of what I want, an image from ESRI best sums it up:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/GUID-42A31756-6518-41E9-A900-2C892AF4023A-web.png

I'm shooting for a z-dimension for time, with one block per day, where observations fall into their appropriate row on the z-axis but remain in their original locations in the x- and y-dimension.

Comment: So `datamatrix` and `timematrix` are arrays?

Comment: I am not quite sure of the heuristic in your series of `if` statements. Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: Why are there `0`s in the `timematrix`? Does `workingdata` start at day 0, on row 1?

Comment: is it me or all `if`'s after the third one are redundant because `locationfinal` can never be greater than 2?

Comment: To elaborate:  No, there shouldn't be any 0's in time.  I have updated this bit of code.  Both `datamatrix` and `timematrix` are 3D arrays.  The `if` statements are all necessary because in my original `for` loop the 3D array is read in one big string (because it's `1:length()` so because of the 3x3 dimensions a remainder 9 gives you an index for the final location of the datapoint in `workingdata`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your `for` loop is doing exactly, and it might perhaps not quite do what you are trying to do. Not sure. For example, check the results of `((1:30)%%9)%%3`.

But, from your description of the problem, you might want to do something like this:

```
workingdata <- array(data = NA, dim = c(3,3,365))
for (i in 1:dim(datamatrix)[1]) {
  for (j in 1:dim(datamatrix)[1]) {
    workingdata[i, j, timematrix[i, j, ]] <- datamatrix[i, j, ]
  }
}
```

Note that this won't work for when you have days that are `0` in your `timematrix` (like in your example data) since R has 1 based indexing.

Comment: Thanks!  This is a much more elegant approach than my example.  Which leads to the crux of my question:  How can I do this without a `for` loop?  They are apparently inefficient and my actual dataset is massive...

Comment: Arrays in R are a bit of a pain when it comes to efficient tools (data.frames are much better that way), but you can have a look at `?plyr::aaply`.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer:  Axeman's solution works in 3 dimensions with the following approach:

```
workingdata <- array(data = NA, dim = c(3,3,365))

for (i in 1:dim(datamatrix)[1]) {
  for (j in 1:dim(datamatrix)[2]) {
    for(k in 1:dim(datamatrix)[3]){
      workingdata[i, j, timematrix[i, j, k]] <- datamatrix[i, j, k]
    }
  }
}
```